# Jenkins configuration to remotely execute batch files via ssh

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, ssh

I have configured publish over ssh plugin through which I am able to send files to another machine, but when I put path for executable file it gives me an error

```
***Building in workspace E:/test/jars
SSH: Connecting from host [****]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [****] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [/abc.bat] ...
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [*****] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [-1]]***
```

I want to execute some batch files on a remote machine via ssh. Both machines are windows 64 bit based. SSH which I have configured is openSSH for windows and files transfer is successful with it. I am configuring a Jenkins job for this task.

Comment: The way I read that log, is that the execution of `/abc.bat` finished with status -1 for some reason. Where is the script copied to because `/abc` is an absolute path and it might not be what you're looking for... perhaps `./abc.bat` or just `abc.bat`?! Lastly, try adding a few lines of debug _here and there_ to figure out what's happening, and also try to run the script manually to see what's going on.

Comment: abc.bat resides on a remote machine, basically, in Jenkins you have to provide the absolute path for the file from where it can execute. 
While executing manually scripts do run successfully.

Comment: I thought it was being copied as well as part of the build. Nonetheless, it does not have to be an absolute path, relative ones work just as well. Also, via ssh the whole `/...` depends on how you setup the user, and that's why I'm asking whether the script is being picked up correctly.

Comment: the abc.bat is placed in the root directory when ssh connection establishes.